# Can ping flooding attacks still be implemented in a IPv6 network?

Tags: ipv6

Can ping flooding attacks still be implemented in a IPv6 network? And what could be a good way to simulate such an attack?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, ping floods can still be implemented in IPv6 networks.** They operate in largely the same manner they do in IPv4 networks. Although IPv6 is a "new" protocol (it was conceived in 1998), there's still plenty of attack vectors to worry about, such as [the Neighbor Discovery Protocol](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-1409) and the massive address space IPv6 occupies.

As far as simulating attacks on an IPv6 network, I would set up a virtual network with your chosen OS and virtualization software, and use a suite like ***THC-IPv6*** to attack the network. [It is a suite used for attacking IPv6 networks](https://www.thc.org/thc-ipv6/). It's got all kinds of goodies. Smurf6 may be of interest to you.

If you want to do some reading on IPv6 security, [this paper](https://www.sba-research.org/wp-content/uploads/publications/Johanna%20IPv6.pdf) is full of good stuff.